# How to retrieve the data using query statement in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

I want to retrieve the data from my table named `cache_image`, but I am not sure how to do that and I am facing an error here.

```
func checkCachedImages() ->Bool{
    database?.open()
    var count = Int()
    for i in images{
        do{
            if let value = database?.executeQuery("SELECT DOWNLOAD_URL FROM CACHED_IMAGE WHERE IMAGE_NAME = ?", withArgumentsIn: [i]){
                while value.next(){
                    print(value.string(forColumn: "IMAGE_NAME"))
                    print(value.string(forColumn: "DOWNLOAD_URL"))
                    count += 1
                    print(count)
                }
            }
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    database?.close()
    if count == images.count{
        print("The count is \(count)")
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

I do have a table named `cached_image` and two columns named `image_name` and `download_url` but when i try to access that using

```
print(value.string(forColumn: "IMAGE_NAME")
```

it is displaying warning :

> Couldn't find image_name and for column "download_url", it is showing "Optional("")"

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: why do you use the "DOWNLOAD_URL" and "IMAGE_NAME" in uppercase

Comment: I don't know because in query statement it was uppercased, so i used so

Comment: can you try to change the table name and columns name to lowercase

Comment: Yeah tried it but still the same @QuocNguyen

Comment: in the example of fmdb, they wrote `try db.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (?)", values: [1])"`, did you double check your querry type, like `(?)`, not `?`, `withArgumentsIn` and `values`

Comment: @QuocNguyen I tried enclosing it with braces still the value is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180256/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-quoc-nguyen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read `image_name` from the result since it isn't part of the `SELECT` clause but you don't need it since you can get it from `i`

```
var numberOfRows = 0
var urls: [String] = ()
print("Image name: \(i)")
if let result = try database?.executeQuery("SELECT download_url FROM CACHED_IMAGE WHERE IMAGE_NAME = ?", values: [i]) {
    while result.next() {
        numberOfRows += 1
        let url = result.stringForColumnIndex(0)
        urls.append(url)
        print("\(url), \(i)")
    }
}
print(numberOfRows)
```

Comment: Hello @Joakim Danielson I tried the above solution , but the print(result.intForColumnIndex(0)) produces 0

Comment: I don't know where you did that print

Comment: I want to print download_url, how to get that?

Comment: I do that, it is in the `url` variable. just modify my print statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180259/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: I have fixed the error, the code should work fine now.

Comment: what was the fix?

Comment: click on the 'Edited...' link

Comment: If you get to the part where `url` is printed but it prints an empty string then it means that a row was found in the database for the image name but the `download_url` column was empty.

Comment: That was the issue, there was no download_url in my table. Thanks a lot